# How can I get the plist from the only one png?

Tags: png, plist

I have a big `png` and a `txt` file. The png is made up by other small pngs. The text describes the info for of those small pngs, like below:

```
obj0 48 48 0.1640625 0.9472656 0.046875 0.046875
obj1 48 48 0.21875 0.6308594 0.046875 0.046875
obj2 48 48 0.21875 0.6816406 0.046875 0.046875
```

I don't have those small pngs and the plist.

And I cannot use the text in my program, because the text just looks like a plist, but it's not. 
How can I get the plist with the only big png and the plist-liked txt? I don't want to cut the BIG png into small pieces, that will cost a lot of time!!

Comment: Here is my solution,
http://blog.csdn.net/l_sharp/article/details/19040351

Comment: The text has the size,hight,width,xy-coordinate of each small pngs.I modify a plist with those info.And make sure the modified-plist matches the big png.Then I use the tool told in that blog to cut the big png into pieces.Finally I ues TexturePacker to get the plist!